# Is there a way to detect whether CollectionView scrolling has been initiated by the user or ScrollTo?

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have a page that hosts a `CollectionView` and `Map`.
there is a list of items, the `ItemsSource` of the `CollectionView` is set to this list and the map pins are drawn based on this list, there's a requirement that when the user scrolls the `CollectionView` the opposite map pin is highlighted, and when the pin is clicked the `CollectionView` is scrolled to that item.

I use `ScrollTo` and `Scrolled` event. but the problem is that when the `ScrollTo` is called the `Scrolled` event is fired too, and that causes a lag or some unexpected behavior. 
I tried to set a flag:

```
private int centerIndex = -1;
bool userScroll;

private void CollectionView_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs args)
{
    if (centerIndex != args.CenterItemIndex)
    {
        if (userScroll)
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, Keys.GoToLocation, args.CenterItemIndex);
        userScroll = true;
        centerIndex = args.CenterItemIndex;
    }
}


private void ScrollToVehicle(object arg1, Item item)
{

    if (collectionView.ItemsSource != null && collectionView.ItemsSource.Cast<Item>().Contains(item))
    {
        userScroll = false;
        collectionView.ScrollTo(item, position: ScrollToPosition.Center, animate: false);
    }
}
```

but the problem is that `Scrolled` event is called multiple times (inside the `if` statement)

Comment: I guess you want to highlight when scroll to the special position, you could use `ScrollTo` method instead of `Scrolled `.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I need to use both. I don't want to fire `Scrolled` event when `ScrollTo` is requested

Answer (score 0):

Try to unsubscribe from the CollectionView_Scrolled before call the ScrollTo

```
collection.Scrolled -= CollectionView_Scrolled;
```